# What's wrong with this class?

Tags: c++, xcode, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create a simple static C++ library that I can link it into a MonoTouch app and invoke the functions via MonoTouch. I'm trying to compile the static library in XCode and have this (edited since ildjarn fixes):

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static int Get5() { return 5; }
    static int Get10() { return 10; }
};
```

I get the following error on the first line:

> Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
>   '**attribute**' before 'MyClass'

Any ideas why?

As an aside can I compile a static library in Visual Studio and link it into a MonoTouch app or is that impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member accessibility decorators are followed by a colon in C++, like labels or switch cases --

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static int Get5() { return 5; }
    static int Get10() { return 10; }
};
```

Also, accessibility decorators have no effect on namespace-scoped types in C++, so `public class MyClass` is nonsensical.

Comment: oh yes, it's been a while since I've written C++ code -_- Unfortunately your fixes have created a new error, 'Unknown type 'class', did you mean 'Class' and the previous error is still present..

Comment: @meds : No, this code compiles perfectly as is: [demonstration](http://ideone.com/D23XL). Whatever problems you're having are related to code you've not shown us.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing Java with C++. Obmit the "public" before the class and change the other "public" to "public:"

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass
{    
    public:
    int Get5()    
    {        
        return 5;    
    }    
    int Get10()    
    {        
       return 10;    
    }
};
```

Or probably you need to compile it with **/clr** compiler flag (with your original code).

Comment: I am sorry, I don't any idea. Not sure if it can compile Managed C++ code. May be you need to export functions/class native way.